# Is it possible to build thesaurus automatically?

Tags: computational-linguistics, corpora

Is it possible to build thesaurus by simply analyzing lots of text, or it's obligatory should be handmade?

*Also a question:* is there free-to-download&use English language thesaurus?

Comment: I personally use [*The Sage*](http://www.sequencepublishing.com/thesage.html).

Comment: Could you specify what kind of thesaurus do you have in mind? Just groups of words with similar meaning? There are a lot of approaches to do so. See, for example, [LSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_indexing|), [Distributional semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributional_semantics) or [deep learning approach](http://deeplearning4j.org/word2vec.html)

Comment: @MaxIonov I need both database of synomyms && antonyms, like one at http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/figure%20out?s=t

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head there's WordNet ([Online interface](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn), [Download](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/download/current-version/)), which is also used by [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/).

I've got no idea how you'd go about making a thesaurus without human intervention. Maybe if you had a thesaurus in language A and a machine translation program trained to translate between language A and language B, it is conceivable that you could use that to get a thesaurus for language B (though of doubtful quality, of course).

Comment: I don't think any one could be fully automated that would be usable without substantial human intervention especially since a good thesarus will also distinguish synonym by semantic meanings.  I reckon hypernyms and hypnyms would be a bit easier (since the primary word in the definition of *pine* would be *tree*, ditto for *oak*, *maple*, etc, so you could link them all as a type of *tree*), but still subject to tons of false negatives and positives.

Answer (score 1):

I second the WordNet answer; I've automatically generated synsets from it for a project where I was attempting to typify lexical (semantic) distance.

As for a great thesaurus, especially if you're a developer, check out [wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/).

Answer (score 1):

If you're aim is to create a Thesaurus for a minority language or a language for which there is not already a large dictionary and/or text corpus, you would probably be well served by using the "[Rapid Word Collection](http://rapidwords.net/)" approach in conjunction with software such as WeSay and/or [FieldWorks Language Explorer (FLEx)](http://fieldworks.sil.org/flex/).

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I'll take a look into those tools. I am mostly interested in English and Russian languages, trying to auto-build thesaurus for the later.

Answer (score 1):

You can also automate this using [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/index.html) with a decent set of documents. For example, see [arxlive](https://arxlive.org/keywords/), which followed the method described in [part 1 of this blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/big-fast-nlp-with-elasticsearch-72ffd7ef8f2e).

Comment: Thanx! Will see.